# How to turn off automount in Ubuntu Server 10.04

Tags: 10.04, server, usb-drive, automount

I have an external USB HDD IDE enclosure that I use to back up and then wipe old hard drives.

My questions is:

How do I prevent Ubuntu Server from auto mounting these drives?

Most of the instructions I've seen online refer to turning off auto mounting for Desktop installs.

EDIT:

To clarify, I am plugging in the usb enclosure AFTER the machine is running. I don't want it to auto mount when I plug in and turn on the power to the external enclosure.

Comment: Is this happening because you also have a desktop like Gnome installed?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen Ubuntu Server automount on default install. I expect that at some point you installed the automount package. If you remove that, it should stop the behavior. msw's instructions for adding the drive to fstab with the noauto mount option are good instructions, though i would add that i recommend using UUID in fstab to id the drive if it's hotpluggable, as the /dev/sdX address may change when you plug the drive in at different times.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by using the `noauto` option in `/etc/fstab` like:

```
UUID=01C4B957CD91E340 /mnt/usbhdd   ext3  noauto,rw,exec 0 0
/dev/sdf1             /mnt/usbhdd   ext3  noauto,rw,exec 0 0
```

Where sometimes the drive is specified by UUID and sometimes device name so I showed both forms.

Comment: That makes sense for a drive that was already set up in fstab. I am asking about a drive being plugged in AFTER the machine was up and running.